# Update row based on other rows sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

Table Details with Data:

```
ID ReferenceNumber Status AuditPeriod  CustomerStatus
1       112        Expired 1/1/2016      
2       113        Pending 1/1/2016     
3       114        Expired 1/1/2016     
4       115        Pending 2/1/2016     
5       116        Approved 2/1/2016
6       117        Pending  2/1/2016
7       118        Approved 3/1/2016
8       119       Approved  3/1/2016
```

Now I need to Update CustomerStatus column by grouping with auditperiod based on 
Status Column.

> - Condition1: If atleast **one status is Expired in auditperiod** then **CustomerStatus is NotCompleted**.
> - Condition2: If atleast **one status is Pending in auditperiod** then **customerstatus is Pending** .
> - Condition3: If **all status are approved** then **customerStatus is Completed**.

Final Output should be as follows:

```
ID ReferenceNumber Status AuditPeriod  CustomerStatus
1       112        Expired 1/1/2016    Not Completed
2       113        Pending 1/1/2016    Not Completed 
3       114        Expired 1/1/2016    Not Completed 
4       115        Pending 2/1/2016     Pending
5       116        Approved 2/1/2016    Pending
6       117        Pending  2/1/2016    Pending 
7       118        Approved 3/1/2016    Completed 
8       119       Approved  3/1/2016    Completed.
```

Please let me know whether this can be done WITH OUT exporting into another temp table (Using single update)

Please let me know if any information is needed from my side

Comment: what have you tried so far? To avoid a temp table you could try using an insert / select combo statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using below query,

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ReferenceNumber, t1.Status, t1.AuditPeriod, t2.CustomerStatus from table1 t1
join (
    select AuditPeriod, 
           CASE 
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Expired' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
               THEN 'Not Completed' 
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
               THEN 'Pending' 
             ELSE 'Completed' 
           END CustomerStatus
     from table1 
     group by AuditPeriod) t2 
 on t1.AuditPeriod = t2.AuditPeriod;
```

I have got the below result,

[image]

Hope this would help you out.